# $k$-form defined in a open set $\omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that if $k$ is odd then $\omega \wedge \omega =0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\omega$ be a $k$-form defined in a open set $\omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that if $k$ id odd then $\omega \wedge \omega =0 $

i tried: i can write $\omega = \sum_{|I|=k} \omega_{I} dx_{I}$ then

$$\omega \wedge  \omega= \sum_{|I|=k}\sum_{|I|=k}(\omega_I \omega_I)dx_I \wedge dx_I  $$ and

$$dx_I \wedge dx_J = (-1)^{\eta} dx_{[I,J]} \text{ if I } \cap J = \emptyset$$
$$dx_I \wedge dx_J = 0 \text{ if  }I \cap J \neq \emptyset$$

$\eta$ is the number of differences $j_r-i_s$ that are $<0$.I'm always getting lost in multi-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only to show that $\omega\wedge\alpha=-\alpha\wedge \omega$  for $\alpha=dx_1\wedge..\wedge dx_{2p+1}$ and $\omega=dy_1\wedge...\wedge dy_{2q+1}$.

$dx_1\wedge..\wedge dx_{2p+1}\wedge dy_1\wedge...\wedge dy_{2q+1}$

$=(-1)^{2p+1}dy_1\wedge dx_1\wedge..\wedge dx_{2p+1}\wedge dy_2\wedge...\wedge dy_{2q+1}$.

Here the fact that $\alpha\wedge dy_1=(-1)^{deg(\alpha)}dy_1\wedge \alpha$ isused.

Then with the same idea you can move successively $dy_i, i>1$ to the left and obtain the result

$\omega=\omega_1+..+\omega_p$ where $\omega_i=dx^i_1\wedge...\wedge dx^i_{2p+1}$

and $\omega\wedge\omega =(\omega_1+...+\omega_p)\wedge (\omega_1+..+\omega_p)$,

since $(\omega_1+..+\omega_p)\wedge\omega_i=-\omega_i\wedge (\omega_1+..+\omega_p)$, you obtain that $\omega\wedge\omega=-\omega\wedge \omega$ and $\omega\wedge\omega =0$.

Comment: showing that $ω∧α=−α∧ω$ if $deg(α)$ and $deg(ω)$ are odd. Using that $\omega \wedge \omega=- \omega \wedge \omega$ then $\omega \wedge \omega + \omega \wedge \omega=0$ Right?

Comment: No, read the proof.

Comment: showing that $ω∧α=−α∧ω$ if $deg(α)$ and $deg(ω)$ are odd. Using that $\omega \wedge \omega=- \omega \wedge \omega$ then $\omega \wedge \omega + \omega \wedge \omega=2(\omega \wedge \omega)=0$ then $\omega \wedge \omega=0$  Right?

Comment: I do not understand why this is wrong

Comment: The point is you use what you need to prove. One cannot write a proof a the fact that the proposition $p$ is true by assuming that as an hypothesis that the proposition $p$ is true.

Comment: Now I understand your demonstration. What I was saying is, if I have this result $ω∧α=−α∧ω$ then is just proceed as Comment

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are of odd degree $p$, then

$$
\beta \wedge \alpha = - \alpha \wedge\beta.
$$
We set $\beta = \alpha$ to have 
$$
\alpha \wedge\alpha = - \alpha \wedge\alpha \Rightarrow 2(\alpha \wedge \alpha) = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha \wedge \alpha = 0.
$$

You can check *Differential Forms with Applications to the Physical Sciences*, by Harley Flanders.